# How to change the erroring code background color in eclipse CDT

Tags: syntax-error, background-color, eclipse-cdt

As you can see below,how to change the background color of erroring code?
[image: How to change the background color of erroring code?]

Comment: Is that background color change permanent, i.e. does it persist if you close and reopen the file?

Comment: @HighCommander4,not permanent,reopening or edit something will remove the color

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that, in addition to the new background color being a poor choice, those lines shouldn't be changing background color at all.

Please [file a bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT) with details.

In the meantime, you can look in `Preferences | General | Appearance | Colors and Fonts` or `Preferences | General | Editors | Text Editors | Appearance color options` to see if you can find the offending background color and change it to something better.